# Seek help to formalize an argument to positiveness of function defined inductively by integral

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, positivity, integral-operators, induction

I have on domain $[0,\infty)$ a known and positive function $f(x)$ and two unknown functions $g(x), h(x)$ that start positive when $x=0$.

I also know that if $h(x)$ is positive, then $g(x)$ is also positive.

I define the induction

$$h(x)=\int_0^x f(t)g(t)h(t) dt$$

I imagine that is possible to say that $h(x)$ (and so $g(x)$) remains positive, but I could not find a formal argument.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By taking the derivative w.r.t. $x$, you get a differential equation for $h$ that should help you.

Comment: Please, why the down vote? Thank you

Comment: @gmvh Thank you!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but some might feel that the question isn't really research-level.

Comment: @gmvh thank you so much. I migrated a little bit from math exchange because here the answers have been faster, but I will try to police myself better on the level. Thank you for clue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the derivative of your "induction" w.r.t. $x$, one gets
$$
h'(x) = f(x)g(x)h(x)
$$
and thus $h'(x)>0$ if $h(x)>0$, according to your conditions. Since $h(0)>0$, one concludes that $h(x)>0$ for $x\in[0;\infty)$.

Comment: Note, though, that your "induction" implies $h(0)=0$.